# In how many ways can you divide 30 people to form two clubs?

Tags: combinatorics

The Quiz club consists of 10 people—a coordinator, 3 researchers, and 6 players.  The
Math Club consists of 20 people—a manager, a coordinator, 4 coaches, 14 players.  In how many
ways can you divide 30 people to form the two clubs and assign roles to individuals? Assume that
a person can be in only one club and can be assigned only one role.

I am thinking of 30!/20!10!. Could someone tell me if I'm thinking correctly or guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Well so far you just have $30\choose{10}$, but you need to consider that after being split into the clubs, we have various ways of assigning the roles. Is the question asking how many ways we can get the people into the two clubs, or is it asking how many different assignments exist for the people?

Comment: @泥九奈加 I guess it's asking how many ways can we divide 30 ppl to form two clubs, so I guess it's how many different assignments exist for the people

Answer (score 3):

[Multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) are particularly strong for this type of problem.

Let quiz club members be described by upper case letters and math club members be described by lower case letters.  Let the letters $c, r, p, h, m$ correspond to coordinators, researchers, players, coaches, and managers respectively.

Redescribe your problem then as counting the number of ways of arranging the string:

$$\underbrace{c}_1\underbrace{rrr}_3\underbrace{pppppp}_6\underbrace{C}_1\underbrace{HHHH}_4\underbrace{PPPPPPPPPPPPPP}_{14}\underbrace{M}_1$$

> $\binom{30}{1,3,6,1,4,14,1} = \frac{30!}{1!3!6!1!4!14!1!}$

$~$

> This is equal of course to the longer more tedious explanation of first splitting up the group of people into two, one of size ten, then from the group of ten choosing a coordinator, from the nine remaining choosing who the researchers are, etc... ending at an expression like $\binom{30}{10}\binom{10}{1}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{6}\binom{20}{1}\binom{19}{4}\binom{15}{14}\binom{1}{1}$